# Computer does not properly wake up from suspend

Tags: 14.04, ati, suspend

I have HP Pavilion G6-2312AX (AMD A10 & ATI dual graphics). I installed Ubuntu 14.04. The PC does not wake up after suspend. All I end up getting is a black screen.

Comment: What happens if you press [Ctrl][Alt][F1] on the black screen?

Comment: The log files `/var/log/pm-*.log` will help. It sounds like your graphics card is not coming back.

Comment: @Fabby nothing happens.. no response at all.

kindly suggest possible edits for the same.

Comment: the CPU is well aware and awake (i tried unlocking by typing the pwd on the blacke screen)... the main issue is, the screen does not come to life..  it is not lit

Answer (score 0):

I ran **Additional Drivers** (invoked via <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, Additional...) and selected the proprietary drivers (`fglrx-updates`) that showed up after a few seconds. It took a minute or so to complete but the progress bar limped along from time to time.

Now I can resume. Researching it wasn't easy perhaps because it does seem to have been a recurring problem over various versions and machines. Hope it works for anyone that needs to try it. Should be easy enough to revert back to Open Source using the same utility.

This is Ubuntu 14.10 on a hp pavilion g6
mem: 3.3Gib
pro: AMD E2-3000M APU with Radeon(tm) HD Graphics × 2
gfx: VESA: SUMO
arc: 64-bit
dsk: 153.7GB